# Sequences question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If the sequence $\{a_n\}$ diverges, would the limit of the sequence $\{a_n\}$ as n goes to $∞ = ±∞.$

Please show how if what I wrote above is right.

Comment: What if $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: In general that need not be true,  consider (-1)^n

Answer (score 1):

A convergent sequence will approach a *specific* finite value.

A divergent sequence is a sequence which does not approach a specific finite value.  This is possible either by the value the sequence approaches is nonreal, for example infinity in the case of $a_n=n$, or it could be that it does not approach a single value, but instead continually varies, never settling on one specific place, for example $a_n=(-1)^n$.

The sequence $\{1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\dots\}$ is not [cauchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) since for small $\epsilon$ one cannot find any $N$ for which all $n,m\geq N$ one has $|a_n-a_m|<\epsilon$ since $|a_n-a_{n+1}|=2$ for all $n$.  As such, it does not converge.